# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview, kitkat

Tengo este error **E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**, pero no sé por qué. He leído diferentes preguntas sobre el mismo tema, pero nada pudo ayudarme

Por otro lado el error no me muestra en Android 5.0, cuando compile el código en android 4.4 este error aparece.

Éste es el código que utilizo, el recyclerview se llena cuando detecta un cambio el **edittext** se llena:

```
EditText txCodeNumber;
public RecyclerView recyclerHarvest;
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;
public RegisterHarvestAdapter adapterRegister;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_monitoring, container, false);

txCodeNumber           = (EditText)       rootView.findViewById(R.id.txcodenumber);
recyclerHarvest = (RecyclerView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerHarvest);

txCodeNumber.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {


                String resultUnit = null;
                Cursor cursoQuantity = new PrHarvestParameter(getActivity()).getConvert(txIdUnit.getText().toString(), txIdProduct.getText().toString(), txIdGrade.getText().toString());

                for (cursoQuantity.moveToFirst(); !cursoQuantity.isAfterLast(); cursoQuantity.moveToNext()) {

                    int value = cursoQuantity.getColumnIndex("value");
                    String values = cursoQuantity.getString(value);
                    resultUnit = String.valueOf((1 * Integer.parseInt(values)));

                }

                arrayLand.add(idtxland.getText().toString());
                arrayGrouper.add(txidGrouper.getText().toString());
                arrayProduct.add(txIdProduct.getText().toString());
                arrayVariety.add(txIdVariety.getText().toString());
                arrayGrade.add(txIdGrade.getText().toString());
                arrayDates.add(inputDate.getText().toString());
                arrayUnits.add(txIdUnit.getText().toString());
                arrayQuantityOrigin.add("1");
                arrayQuantity.add(resultUnit);
                arrayUser.add(shareIdUser);
                arrayCode.add(txCodeNumber.getText().toString());


                recyclerHarvest.setHasFixedSize(true);
                lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerHarvest.setLayoutManager(lManager);

                final List<ConstructRegisterHarvest> ListComplete = getCursorList(arrayCode, arrayQuantity);
                adapterRegister = new RegisterHarvestAdapter(ListComplete, getActivity());
                recyclerHarvest.setAdapter(adapterRegister);
                recyclerHarvest.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                txCodeNumber.setText("");

                contador++;
                txQuantity.setText("" + contador);
            }
            return false;

    });

return rootView;
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas gracias!

**EDITADO**

Este es el adapter:

```
public class RegisterHarvestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RegisterHarvestAdapter.syncronizationViewHolder> {

    private Context mainContext;
    private List<ConstructRegisterHarvest> items;
    ArrayList<Integer> dataResolve = new ArrayList<>();

    public RegisterHarvestAdapter(List<ConstructRegisterHarvest> items, Context contexto) {
        this.mainContext = contexto;
        this.items = items;
    }

    static class syncronizationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        // Campos respectivos de un item
        protected TextView Code;
        protected TextView Quantity;

        public syncronizationViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            this.Code     = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txCode);
            this.Quantity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txQuantity);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public syncronizationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_register_harvest, parent, false);

        return new syncronizationViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RegisterHarvestAdapter.syncronizationViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final ConstructRegisterHarvest item = items.get(position);
        viewHolder.itemView.setTag(item);
        viewHolder.Code.setText("" + item.getCode() );
        viewHolder.Quantity.setText("" + item.getQuantity());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el adapter ?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta con el código del adapter @Israel

Comment: No consigo reproducir el error, ni consigo encontrar que es lo que va mal, el Logcat no te da mas informacion ?

Comment: No de errores sólo me da ese, lo que pasa es que Android 5.0 para arriba no sale el error, pero cuando lo compilo en Android 4.4 sale ese error. Me sale esta información también pero debe ser de proceso no se si tenga que ver Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. @Israel

Comment: Ese mensaje es normal, prueba a iniciar en el `onCreate` el objeto adapter y asignarle el layoutManager: `adapterRegister = new RegisterHarvestAdapter(ListComplete, getActivity());
lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerHarvest.setLayoutManager(lManager);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solución definitiva, recién acabo de resolver este error.
El problema reside en que primero debes inicializar tus componentes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private List<Contacto> milista=new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AdaptContacto adaptContacto;
private LinearLayoutManager manager;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerContacto);        
    manager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adaptContacto=new AdaptContacto(milista);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptContacto);        
}
```

De esta manera no mostrara en el Logcat ese fastidioso error. Ahora cuando tu lista reciba datos, simplemente llama a el adaptador e informale que se añadio a la lista(la cual debe ser Global) asi:

```
adaptContacto.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Espero haberte Ayudado :)